# C/C++ Сжатие массива( удалить элементы)

Tags: c++, c, массивы, удаление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    float A[N];
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf ("%f",&A[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if (i%2==0) {
            sum += A[i];
        }
    }
    int i1, n2;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (A[i]<0) {
            i1=i;
            break;
        }   
    }
    for (i = i1; i < N; i++) {
        if (A[i]<0) {
            n2=i;
        }
    }
    float pr = 1;
    for (i = i1; i <= n2; i++) {
        pr=pr* A[i];
    }
    float B[N];
    int k;
    for (i = 0 , k =0; i < N; i++) {
        if  (fabs(A[i])>1){
            B[k]=A[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("%.4f\n", sum);  
    printf("%.4f\n", pr); 
    for ( i = 0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%.4f ", B[i]);

    
    return 0;
}
```

С первыми двумя пунктами проблем вроде бы нет.Но проблема в последнем.Вот первый тест, почему то выводит -1...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй тест. Тут всё в порядке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Третий тест..Почему то возвращает огромное значение, вместо 0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если я оставляю только эту часть кода, то третий тест отрабатывает корректно

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    float A[N];
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf ("%f",&A[i]);
    }

    float B[N];
    int k;
    for (i = 0 , k =0; i < N; i++) {
        if  (fabs(A[i])>1){
            B[k]=A[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i<N; i++)
    printf("%.4f ", B[i]);

    
    return 0;
}
```

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, в чем дело.

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm там есть корректное удаление элементов.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019 ещё есть.

Answer (score 0):

В первых двух примерах у вас есть отрицательные элементы массива, в последнем - нет. Соответственно переменные `int i1, n2;` не инициализированы. При последующих попытках их использования (в циклах удаления элементов) и происходит ошибка. Исправьте на

```
int i1 = 0, n2 = 0;
```

Все будет работать.